# Azure data factory copy activity dynamic mapping error : Syntax error: Missing comma between arguments

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to convert json to csv and want to use dynamic mapping instead of manual mapping. I dynamic mapping I see an error message  Syntax error: Missing comma between arguments

below is the json iam trying to add in dynamic content

```
{
            "type": "TabularTranslator",
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "source": {
                        "path": "$['longitude']"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "longitude",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "path": "$['City']"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "City",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "path": "$['temeprature']"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "temeprature",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "path": "$['max']"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "max",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "path": "$['speed']"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "speed",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

See error message in this screenshot

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because the incorrect format used to specify dynamic mapping. The following is a demonstration on the same.

- I got the same error when I used the JSON syntax that you have used for mapping columns dynamically i.e., `Syntax error: Missing comma between arguments`.

[image]

- Since we are mapping the source columns (json) to destination (csv), we can specify the source in the mapping as **`"name": "longitude"`**. I considered only longitude column for this demonstration and the following is the JSON that I used for mapping:

```
@json('{
            "type": "TabularTranslator",
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "longitude"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "longitude",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "city"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "city",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }'
)
```

- When the pipeline is run, it successfully writes the input JSON file as a CSV (below is the image of my csv output).

[image]